# Interprete Data for Load Testing

Tags: php, mysql, load

I'm load testing my server to understand where the bottleneck is. I started load testing an empty php script just to have some reference data, and I found something that I cannot explain myself.
When I start hitting an empty php page with 50 users, I can reach about 35 request per second (both cpu and memory are not bound at all).
Now I was curious to know what happened when "simulating" db interaction, so I just added a query (mysql via msqli) that looks like `DO SLEEP(1);`, and I see that the request per second are now about 20.

I expected to be still 35 request per second once after a little bit, is not reasonable? Do you see some obvious reason because I don't reach the same request per second?

Comment: A `SLEEP` call makes the worker handling that request take longer. Typically, your server would have a maximum number of simultaneous workers configured, and more concurrent requests than that would be queued.

Comment: Good point, but my MaxClients is way higher, I can reach easily 400 request per second on an empty php script (where the bottleneck is the client that can't send more), that means that those requests are not queued at least not up to 400, and since the sleep is just 1 second, I would expect to maintain the 35 request per second